# How to find the package to which a function belongs to

Tags: package, julia

Imagine you find in someone code a function (e.g. `countfrom`). How to find the package to which a function belongs to? In this case `Iterators`.

Comment: I found that the package `Iterators` has been deprecated and now the function must be used as `Iterators.countfrom`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`@which`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.@which) macro:

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> @which countmap(rand(1:10, 100))
countmap(x::AbstractArray{T,N} where N; alg) where T in StatsBase at C:\Users\user\.julia\packages\StatsBase\548SN\src\counts.jl:389
```

Note that as the docs say, the macro actually evaluates the arguments to the specific call, as a function might have different methods defined in different places.

Comment: really it's so cool.