# Check a function belongs to which package in Julia

Tags: package, julia

Sometimes I wonder if a function belongs to which package. So I can use the `@which` macro for this purpose according to [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893007/how-to-see-what-package-a-function-comes-from)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61660692/how-to-find-the-package-to-which-a-function-belongs-to)]. But today, I was confronted with a strange case I provided here:

```
julia> @which Not
InvertedIndices

(@v1.7) pkg> st
      Status `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.7\Project.toml`
  [6e4b80f9] BenchmarkTools v1.3.1
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.10.4
  [8f4d0f93] Conda v1.7.0
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v1.3.4
  [864edb3b] DataStructures v0.18.13
  [85a47980] Dictionaries v0.3.21
  [31c24e10] Distributions v0.25.64
  [38e38edf] GLM v1.8.0
  [09f84164] HypothesisTests v0.10.10
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.23.3
  [70c4c096] Indicators v0.8.1
  [8ef0a80b] Languages v0.4.3
  [bdcacae8] LoopVectorization v0.12.119
  [945b72a4] MarketData v0.13.12
  [4f8c86c6] MarketTechnicals v0.6.0
  [2774e3e8] NLsolve v4.5.1
  [47be7bcc] ORCA v0.5.0
  [5fb14364] OhMyREPL v0.5.12
  [f0f68f2c] PlotlyJS v0.15.0
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.31.1
  [438e738f] PyCall v1.93.1
  [d330b81b] PyPlot v2.10.0
  [3646fa90] ScikitLearn v0.6.4
  [2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.33.18
  [f3b207a7] StatsPlots v0.14.34
  [22787eb5] Term v1.0.2
  [f8ef4a19] VirtualEnv v1.0.0
  [a945a9ba] WordNet v0.2.2
  [fdbf4ff8] XLSX v0.7.10
  [f43a241f] Downloads
```

The macro said, `Not` belongs to `InvertedIndices`. But as you can see, I don't have any package with that name. So I'm confused and can't understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have `Not` introduced into your `Main` module by `using DataFrames`, and DataFrames.jl re-exports it from InvertedIndices.jl, as you can see [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/14e682b623ccc07d34cb7399f79311e9443f9b13/src/DataFrames.jl#L5).

You do not have to have InvertedIndices.jl in your Project.toml, but it is present in your Manifest.toml.

Comment: It's a little complicated  So you mean `InvertedIndices.jl` automatically got imported after I imported `DataFrames` using `using DataFrames`? So I wish REPL somehow exposes that in this case, like: *"The `Not` comes from `DataFrames` and its dependencies."*

Comment: No - it is not exposed unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to see the dependencies of a package that is in the current environment:

```
using Pkg

function pkgdeps(pkg::AbstractString)
    uuid = Pkg.project().dependencies[pkg]
    pkginfo = Pkg.dependencies()[uuid]
    return pkginfo.dependencies
end
```

Example:

[image: pkgdeps function]

Comment: Thanks, Elias. This function can help a lot! ✨

Comment: You can also use this package: https://github.com/peng1999/PkgDependency.jl

Comment: Thanks! Fantastic and handy as well! I guess the combination of the proposed package with [`Term.jl`](https://github.com/FedeClaudi/Term.jl) would be nice.